# Where are the themes stored in the Atom Editor?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

I would like to edit an existing theme that I have installed in my editor. I would like to make some personal changes to it.

Where can I find the file that defines the syntax? I did some researches on Google, but I don't seem to find an answer to my question!

Comment: Just to add to this you can also go to your Atom settings > themes > click the gear next to the theme that's selected then click view code where it opens an atom window for you to edit everything.

Answer (score 1):

On a Linux/UNIX based system, like a Mac, you can find your installed themes in your home directory:

```
ls -ald ~/.atom/packages/*-syntax ~/.atom/packages/*-ui
```